# Custom maker in Symfony MakerBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony5

In **Symfony MakerBundle** docs there is a word about creating own makers. It says to:

> create a class that extends AbstractMaker in your src/Maker/
> directory. And this is really it!

Slow down there.
What about a custom template/skeleton for this new maker? I checked in `Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Generator` class and it searches for templates like this:

```
$templatePath = __DIR__.'/Resources/skeleton/'.$templateName;
```

So when running custom maker (command) the path is still set to Symfony MakerBundle resources. Am I missing something? No clean way to generate files from custom templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I look at the code in `Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Generator` I see this:

```
 private function addOperation(string $targetPath, string $templateName, array $variables)
    {
        if ($this->fileManager->fileExists($targetPath)) {
            throw new RuntimeCommandException(sprintf('The file "%s" can\'t be generated because it already exists.', $this->fileManager->relativizePath($targetPath)));
        }

        $variables['relative_path'] = $this->fileManager->relativizePath($targetPath);

        $templatePath = $templateName;
        if (!file_exists($templatePath)) {
            $templatePath = __DIR__.'/Resources/skeleton/'.$templateName;

            if (!file_exists($templatePath)) {
                throw new \Exception(sprintf('Cannot find template "%s"', $templateName));
            }
        }

        $this->pendingOperations[$targetPath] = [
            'template' => $templatePath,
            'variables' => $variables,
        ];
    }
```

So basically, it first checks if the file exists, if it doesn't it changes the template's path to `__DIR__.'/Resources/skeleton/'.$templateName;` and if that file doesn't exist either, it then throws an exception.

So basically, if you provide a file path that exists to the `$templateName` argument, you can decide where the template is loaded from.

Comment: Thanks! I was too focused on original makers and passing just 'dir/templatename'. Have a nice day :)